Why does LazyHStack render the first 3 views therefore calling onAppear too early?
I want to toggle a Boolean state when a view is visible in the phone screen.
I've made the LazyHStack as below however, the following 2 views, somehow is already appeared. I tried using the new API onScrollVisibilityChange(threshold: 1,..) and the result is the same.
How can I just make sure that only the right view turns true ?
import SwiftUI

let quotes: [String] = [
    "11 Life is full of possibilities You just need to know where to look.",
    "22 The only thing predictable about life is its unpredictability",
    "33 You and I are a team. Nothing is more important than our friendship.",
    "44 I don’t care what they’re going to say. Let the storm rage on. The cold never bothered me anyway.",
    "55 When you’re curious, you find lots of interesting things to do."
]

struct TryScrollView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(quotes, id: \.self) { quote in
                    TestView(text: quote)
                }
            }
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
    }
}

struct TestView: View {

    @State var isVisible: Bool = false

    let text: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .font(.system(.title))
                .padding()
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .fill(.blue)
                )
        }
        .frame(width: 320, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(24)
        .onScrollVisibilityChange(threshold: 1, { visible in
            print("\(text) is visible") //--> I want to toggle isVisible here
        })
        .onAppear {
            print("\(text) appears") //--> I want to toggle isVisible here
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TryScrollView()
}



Huh that's certainly not what the documentation of onScrollVisibilityChange says it will do. I'd consider this a SwiftUI bug until iOS 18 fully releases. In the mean time, I think you could do something like this.

I couldn't believe my eyes too ... the moment I hit Run, the log says it all :)
